# How to render multiindex pivot table in tkinter GUI?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am looking how to display multiindexed pivot table in GUI application based on `tkinter`. I am interested mainly in data display, no need for interactive editing / view customization.

So far I found `pandas` for actual pivot tables generating. But I have problem getting it displayed in `tkinter`. As far as I understand, `pandas` renders to console in textmode. It can also render to `Jupyter Notebook` in graphic mode, but not to `tkinter` widgets / windows.

I know about `pandastable` that works under `tkinter`, but this package seems to not support multiindex pivot tables. When I use

```
      table.pivot()
```

the program shows me standard `pandastable`'s popup dialog that asks for only one index and only one column, whereas I need multiple grouping levels (multiple indices) and multiple columns, without any popup dialog. I was playing with `dataexplore.exe` and was unable to get that. I suspect it is impossible within `pandastable`.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: If you are ok with displaying text, you can always render the output of `table.pivot(...).to_string()`.

Comment: Printing text should be good enough. Thanks for this tip!

Answer (score -1):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Jim', 'Jill'],
        'Age': [28, 24, 32, 35],
        'Salary': [50000, 60000, 45000, 70000],
        'Department': ['HR', 'Engineering', 'Sales', 'Engineering']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a pivot table
pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index='Department', values=['Age', 'Salary'], aggfunc={'Age': 'mean', 'Salary': 'sum'}).reset_index()

# Define a function to display the pivot table
def display_pivot_table():
    pivot_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    pivot_window.title("Pivot Table")

    # Create a Treeview widget
    tree = ttk.Treeview(pivot_window)

    # Set column headings
    tree['columns'] = list(pivot_table.columns)
    for col in pivot_table.columns:
        tree.column(col, anchor='w')
        tree.heading(col, text=col)

    # Insert data into the table
    for _, row in pivot_table.iterrows():
        tree.insert("", 'end', values=tuple(row))

    # Pack the Treeview widget
    tree.pack()

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tkinter with Pivot Table")

# Create a button to display the pivot table
button = ttk.Button(root, text="Display Pivot Table", command=display_pivot_table)
button.pack(pady=20)

# Start the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The question was on how to render a table containing multiindices. This solution does not contain any multiindex.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).